# Selecting without repeating class

Tags: css

is there any way to do this (without SASS, LESS etc..):

```
.main_class{

   .subclass_1{
      property: value;
   }
   .subclass_2{
      property: value;
   }
   .subclass_3{
      property: value;
   }

}
```

instead of this (4 declarations of main_class):

```
   .main_class .subclass_1{
        property: value;
    }
    .main_class .subclass_2{
        property: value;
    }
   .main_class .subclass_3{
        property: value;
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to use the main class anyway? You should use an ID if the element really needs its unique css properties

Comment: This is exactly what `SASS` and `LESS` are for... It's like your asking 'Can I make a phone call... Without using a phone?'... You asking us to come up with a solution whilst casually mentioning the solution and then saying 'no this please' :)

Comment: @BBQ. I need "main_class" fore example because of mobile-devices recognization.

somethinghere I wanted to know for sure that this is not possible. :)

Comment: @user2997914 [Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) exist for this purpose.

Comment: This is css, not any programming language like js to use nesting. You have to use less or scss

Comment: @BBQ. Thank you.Of course I use media-queries but I need more specific classing than media queries can offer.